# php mvc quiz - checking the answers

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to do a simple quiz using Codeigniter2.2.4 but I'm having some issues with checking the answers.
I have the following structure:
controllers: Guess
models: People
views:  guessview, results

in my people class I have a methods to get all questions from the database and to get a random one. I'm having issues checking if the answer is right or no. It always comes back false

```
function getQuestions()
{
    if(!isset($questions))
    {
        $this->db->select("id, name, choice1, choice2, correctAnswer");
    $this->db->from('questions');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
    $questions[] = $row;
    }
    }

    return $questions;
}

function getRandomQuestion()
{
    $max = count($this->getQuestions());
    $randpos = rand(0, $max-1);
    $question = $this->getQuestions()[$randpos];

    return $question;
}
```

And in my controller :

```
function guess()
{
    $answer = $this->input->get('answers',false);
    //$questionId = $this->input->get('id',false);

        //this will generate random questions.
        $newQuestion = $this->people->getRandomQuestion();
        $this->load->view('guessview',$newQuestion);
        //this is always false
       if($answer == $newQuestion->correctAnswer)
       {
           //do something
       }
}
```

And in my view I have only a form displaying only one question at a time.

//Update
When using the function you provided I'm getting some errors in my controller and view. I try grabbing a question in my controller

```
 $question = $this->people->getRandomQuestion();
```

//this give me undefined index correctAnswer but should it not have since the database table has the following structure : id, name, choice1, choice2,   correctAnswer ?

```
if($question['correctAnswer'] == $answer)
{
}
```

Also when I want to pass data to the view i.e

```
$question = $this->people->getRandomQuestion();
$data['question'] = $question;
$this->load->view('guessview',$data);
```

And in my view for the form values I tried like this: $question['name'], $question['id'] and I get undefined index name,id etc.

My form from guessview.php

```
<form id= "form1" class="form"  action="<?php echo base_url();?>guess/people" method='POST'>
                <input type=hidden name=id value="<?php echo $question['id'] ?>"> 
                <label><?php echo $question['name'] ?>
                <div class="radio">
                  <label>
                    <input type="radio" id='rad1' name="answers" value="<?php echo $question['choice1'] ?>">
                    <?php echo $question['choice1'] ?>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio">
                  <label>
                    <input type="radio" name="answers"  value="<?php echo $question['choice2'] ?>">
                    <?php echo $question['choice2'] ?>
                  </label>
                </div>
                <div class="radio">
                <label>
                <input type="radio" name="answers"   value="<?php echo $question['correctAnswer'] ?>">
                <?php echo $question['correctAnswer'] ?>
                </label>
                <div>
                    <input type=submit name="sub" value="Answer">
                </div>
</form>
```

The problem why I posted was regarded to the controller function. It seems that when I try to check if the user answered correctly  is always false. Like what the user answered the previous question get compared with the correctAnswer of the current question.

I tried getting the input of the radio button and id(put in a hidden field)
if these were returning false it meant that no questions are display and displayed first question. else if there was input then get the question based on the id and compare the question's correctAnswer to what the user selected.(But like I said above it would always be false). I will post the method when I get home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in single Model function

```
function getRandomQuestion()
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1 )";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    $result = $query->result_array();

    $count = count($result);

    if (empty($count) ||$count > 1) {
        echo "Inavliad Question";
    }
    else{
        return $result;
    }
}
```